# tableau visualization issue with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, tableau

I'm New to LWC and I'm trying to include tableau visualization with LWC. I have a combobox where I store all my tableau urls. On combobox change i'm chaning the url value but the view is not re-rendering for some reason.

Am I missing something here?

html:

```
<div class = "slds-var-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-combobox
        label="Select a report"
        value={vizUrl}
        placeholder="Select a report"
        options={vizOptions}
        onchange={handleVizChange}></lightning-combobox>
    </div>

    <template if:true={vizUrl}>
        <c-tableau-viz viz-url={vizUrl}></c-tableau-viz>
        </template>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

javascript in lwc:

```
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    
    export default class TableauReports extends LightningElement {
    vizUrl;
        handleVizChange(event) 
        {
            this.vizUrl = event.detail.value;
        }
}
```

Comment: To compute a value for the property, use a getter

Comment: I tried adding the getter setter but it throws ' [Maximum call stack size exceeded]' error.
@api
    vizUrl;
    get vizUrl() {
        return this.vizUrl;
    }
    set vizUrl(value) {
        this.vizUrl = value;
    }

Comment: you should not name your getter and property the same.